# Is there an adapter for using USB headphones with a 1/8" (or 1/4") plug?

Tags: usb, headphones, headset

I have the Creative Labs Arena headphones, and I want to use them with other devices than my PC. The only problem is that they are USB. Is there some kind of adapter that I can use to change the USB plug to a standard 1/8" connector?

Comment: Sell the Creative, buy a Sennheiser, double win :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would be very surprised if there is such an adapter. the main problem stems from the fact that the Digital-Analog-Converter in the headset requires an active power source to function, which you typically won't get over a stereo cable. Also, most likely USB headphones from different manufacturers do not use the same software interface, which would require any such analog to digital converter to have some sort of ability to have drivers installed. Add to that the fact that you would also be going from analog to digital and back to analog there would probably be a noticeable loss of sound quality.

my suggestion, if you absolutely had to do this, would be to get a netbook or small laptop (for portability) that has a line-in port. whatever OS you use will need to support the ability to pass through any input to the output as well. then install the software for your headphones and in the audio control panel set the default input device as the line-in port/device and the default output device as the headphones. if applicable, additional settings may need to be set in any audio application manager (such as is commonly installed by RealTek's drivers on Windows).

Answer (score 3):

To be fair I have not seen such a thing, but I would not be surprised if it was more expensive than a decent pair of headphones.